# What happens when you call RWByteAddressBuffer.InterlockedAdd?

Tags: hlsl

I usually program in OpenGL but I need to translate some code from HLSL.

I have seen the documentation of [RWByteAddressBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwbyteaddressbuffer), but I'm not sure how it works with [InterlockedAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwbyteaddressbuffer-interlockedadd).

Suposedly, `RWByteAddressBuffer` is addressed by bytes. However, I think `InterlockedAdd` works on `uint`s,  which are 32-bit unsigned integers.

My doubt is, what happens when I do this?

```
uint c;
buffer.InterlockedAdd(0, 1, c);
```

Am I incrementing the first byte of the buffer, or the first 32-bit word of the buffer? What if I use offsets that are not multiples of 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call :

```
uint c;
uint location = 0;
buffer.InterlockedAdd(location, 1, c);
```

Location is specified in bytes, but you are indeed increasing 1 on the first 4 bytes (int size).

As per documentation, ByteAddressBuffer/RWByteAddressBuffer memory offsets need to be multiple of 4, anything else is undefined.

See (Byte Address Buffer section): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-cs-resources

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it looks like I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes it's a bit confusing to call something byteaddress while working exclusively with int sized data, been there :)